# Make sure AudioSource is routed to a mixer that ResonanceAudioRenderer is attached to. [Unity Warning]

Tags: unity-game-engine, resonance-audio

I keep being spammed by this warning in Unity when using audio sources not routed to the ResonanceAudioMixer. But I don't want ALL the audio to be routed to it, because I spatialise only a some of the sounds of my game, so the question is: would it be safe to get rid of this warning by code (for performance reasons)? Why would ResonanceAudio keep spamming me with this warning (999+) if I am allowed by design to route the audio also to other mixers?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Why would ResonanceAudio keep spamming me with this warning (999+) if
>   I am allowed by design to route the audio also to other mixers?

This is more like a reminder to remind users to make sure that AudioSource is routed to a mixer that the ResonanceAudioRenderer is attached to. Nothing more. If you know what you are doing then simply ignore it.

> would it be safe to get rid of this warning by code (for performance
>   reasons)?

You don't have to do this because it will not affect performance. It won't show up in a build. You will only see this warning in the Editor. The [`UNITY_EDITOR`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) preprocessor directive is used to make that warning show in the Editor only.